# C++: Prompt Requires Data to be Inputted Multiple Times to Proceed

Tags: c++, random, cin

The following program I wrote prompts the user to input a number 1 - 100. The program has a pre-selected number from a random number generator that the user has to guess. If the user's guess is too high or low then the program will notify the user until the user's guess is right. My program works well, but when prompted to input a number I have to input the number four or more times in some case for the program to prompt me. Could someone show me or help me to find my mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>//A user stated that using this piece of code would make a true randomization process.
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()//When inputing a number, sometimes the user has to input it more than once.
{
    int x;
    int ranNum;
    srand( time(0));

    ranNum = rand() % 100 + 1;

    cout << "Please input your guess for a random number between 1 - 100.\n";
    cin >> x;

    while (x > ranNum || x < ranNum)
    {
        {
            if (x > ranNum)
                cout << "Your input was greater than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
            cin >> x;
            if (x > 100 || x < 1)
                cout << "Input invalid. Please input a number between 1 - 100.\n";
            cin >> x;
        }
        {
            if (x < ranNum)
                cout << "Your input was less than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
            cin >> x;
            if (x > 100 || x < 1)
                cout << "Input invalid. Please input a number between 1 - 100.\n";
            cin >> x;
        }
        {
            if (x == ranNum)
                cout << "You guessed right!\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (x > ranNum || x < ranNum)` Whoops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brackets are in the wrong place.  An if statement that has mutiple lines should be in the form of

```
if (condition)
{
    code1
    code2
    code3
    ...
}
```

What you have is

```
{
    if condition
        code1
        code2
        code3
        ...
}
```

So `code1` will only run when condition is true but `code2`, `code3` and the rest will run no matter what.  Indentation does not count for anything in C++.  We could have (please never do this):

```
            if (condition)
    {
code1
code2
        code3
}
```

And all three lines would be ran in the if statement.

Your code corrected to have the brackets in the correct place would be

```
while (x != ranNum)
{
    if (x > ranNum)
    {
        cout << "Your input was greater than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
        cin >> x;
        if (x > 100 || x < 1)
        {
            cout << "Input invalid. Please input a number between 1 - 100.\n";
            cin >> x;
        }
    }
    if (x < ranNum)
    {
        cout << "Your input was less than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
        cin >> x;
        if (x > 100 || x < 1)
        {
            cout << "Input invalid. Please input a number between 1 - 100.\n";
            cin >> x;
        }
    }
    if (x == ranNum)
        cout << "You guessed right!\n";
}
```

I also changed `while (x > ranNum || x < ranNum)` to `while (x != ranNum)` as we only want to run the loop while `x` is not equal to `ranNum`

Comment: Correct, and there's a similar instance in the nested conditions. OP seems to be expecting indentation to have semantics.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Having the brackets in the right position solved the problem I was having.

Comment: @BillFisher No problem.  If this or any other answer here solved the problem you might consider accepting it by clicking the check mark.  This shows that the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `if` statements properly:

```
{
    if (x > ranNum)
        cout << "Your input was greater than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
    cin >> x;
    if (x > 100 || x < 1)
        cout << "Input invalid. Please input a number between 1 - 100.\n";
    cin >> x;
}
```

Both`if` conditions above don't affect anything but whether output messages are printed, and surrounding curly braces are useless too. When conditioned code consists of more than single statement, you need to wrap it into curly braces:

```
{
    if (x > ranNum)
    {
        cout << "Your input was greater than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
        cin >> x;
    }
    if (x > 100 || x < 1)
    {
        cout << "Input invalid. Please input a number between 1 - 100.\n";
        cin >> x;
    }
}
```

Also there's no point in duplicating code that reads input and performs range checking. The following looks more straightforward to me:

```
int main()
{
    int ranNum;
    srand( time(0));

    ranNum = rand() % 100 + 1;

    cout << "Please input your guess for a random number between 1 - 100.\n";
    cin >> x;

    int x;
    for (;;) // Endless loop
    {                  
        cin >> x;

        if (x > 100 || x < 1)
        {
            cout << "Input invalid. Please input a number between 1 - 100.\n";
            continue; // Jump to next iteration of the loop
        }                                             

        if (x == ranNum)                              
        {
            cout << "You guessed right!\n";
            break; // Leave the loop
        }

        if (x > ranNum)
            cout << "Your input was greater than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
        else
            cout << "Your input was less than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>//A user stated that using this piece of code would make a true randomization process.
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()//When inputing a number, sometimes the user has to input it more than once.
{
    int x;
int ranNum;
srand(time(0));

ranNum = rand() % 100 + 1;

cout << "Please input your guess for a random number between 1 - 100.\n";


while (x > ranNum || x < ranNum)
{
    cin >> x;
    if (x > ranNum && x<=100 & x>=1) cout << "Your input was greater than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
    else if (x < ranNum && x<=100 & x>=1) cout << "Your input was smaller than the system's generated random number. Please try again.\n";
    else if (x>=100 || x<=1) cout << "Input invalid. Please input a number between 1 - 100.\n";

}
cout << "You guessed right!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

In future:

When you use while loop, it includes if statement in it. Use is properly. Also, try nt to nest if statements but use logical operators instead.

Comment: You forgot to initialize x before you evaluate it in the while loop condition.